# Jmeter Extracting unique parameters response

Tags: json, api, jmeter, response

I just want to extract version parameter but if found I multiple/duplicate values example `2-327RC212` it will return me once and move with succeeding.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what do you want? Extract the values without the duplicates? If yes - you will need to switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and write your extraction logic in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

You could use [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class to fetch the values and store them into a HashSet, then add each value from the [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) into JMeter Variables.

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: I want to extract all values but will return once only even it has a duplicate values.

Comment: I understand your requirement do not

Comment: Example for Response version parameter it generated multiple values, "1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5, 1 ,2 ,3 4" and I only want to extract 1,2,3,4,5 regardless how many duplicated value generated

Comment: Then my above answer is applicable